# Add a new event in textView pop-up

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextview

I am using in my app a selectable `UITextView`. You know the pop-up for copy from `UITextView`.

[image]

I want to know if it's possible to add a new Event/Action in this pop-up and how can i do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UIMenuController`singleton and add to it a new `UIMenuItem`

Answer (score 0):

U can use below Code

```
UIMenuItem *testMenuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Info" action:@selector(handleInfo:)];
[[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuItems: @[testMenuItem]];
[[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setTargetRect:CGRectMake(310, 25, 50, 50) inView:self];
[[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] update];
```

Also Refer below links

http://iphonedev.tv/blog/2014/4/17/show-the-uimenucontroller-and-display-custom-edit-menus-for-uiviewcontroller-uitableviewcontroller-and-uicollectionview-on-ios-7

http://nshipster.com/uimenucontroller/

Hope it helps you...!